# Twitter widget _bigger profile pictures

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm using the official Twitter search and list widgets on my site but would like larger profile images than the widget provides by default.

The image it outputs has a url like follows: http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2345779363/4x1fuaqbec4ef62163yd_normal.png

Notice the '_normal' at the end. Twitter adds this on to all profile pictures to make them smaller. What I want is for 'normal' to be replaced by 'bigger' which, as you may expect, outputs a bigger image.

Here's the script Twitter calls. http://twitter.com/javascripts/widgets/widget.js

Is there a way that I can either
a) modify the script to output the _bigger images
b) do a sort of 'find and replace' once the code is outputted to change '_normal' to '_bigger'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within the features  set:

```
fullscreen: true,
```

that kicks off a part of the script that replaces _normal to _bigger.

Comment: Hmm, that gives the image of dimensions of the bigger image but keeps the actual normal pixelated image. I expect that's not supposed to happen. http://nonaynever.net/